# Remove links from close question dialog for moderators

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, close-dialog

Currently, if you want to cast a binding vote as a moderator, you are presented with the standard close dialog which gives you access to a number of radio buttons.

The great thing about radio buttons in HTML is that you can click anywhere within the text that is encapsulated by the corresponding `<label>` tag and it will select that item.

This is a very good thing, as it doesn't force you to try and click on a tiny area to select the item.

However, closing a question as "Off Topic" gives you this:

[image]

Note the circled area.

The problem here is that more often than not, I'm clicking *exactly* on that link; I suppose that it's because we're still drawn to the vicinity of the radio button (which explains why I don't click the text block on the right).

This leads to taking me out of the moderation queue when I really wanted to select an item on a dialog.  Not a good UX.

Moderators know where the `/faq` is (and the link is on *every* page of the site), so putting it in the close dialog for them is especially redundant.

Please remove the links from the close dialog so that we aren't taken out of the queue or off the question (if not in the queue) while trying to perform moderator duties.

Comment: [Can the links be disabled in the vote-to-close dialog?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136270/can-the-links-be-disabled-in-the-vote-to-close-dialog)

Comment: Could a workaround be just to not click on that link? *ducks*

Comment: @JNK I've already explained in the question why that's not practical; the natural inclination is to shift to the left where the radio buttons are, but click on the larger target (the paragraph).  Since the FAQ link is right in that area it's clicked on more often than not.  I'm sure it wasn't done on purpose, but the location is really sub-optimal for the purposes of moderation.

Comment: Reopened because I'm asking for this specifically for moderators as opposed to the community at large.  The two are for separate groups of people, and may or may not be addressed independently.

Comment: But... but... but what if one don't know how to get to the [faq]!

Comment: @HugoDozois If that person is a moderator, then they have bigger problems.

Comment: **Similar same issue elsewhere** – I never had this very issue. But very often I hit the superuser link when voting to close off-topic questions belonging to superuser. Unfortunately.

Comment: Alternatively: get rid of the descriptions altogether. Just have large hotspots for the radio buttons with just the close reason text and nothing else.

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing earlier when I hit the FAQ for the 100th time by accident on my mobile.