# Spammy answer undeleted but hidden on user profile (after flag dispute?)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-page, spam, information-display

Someone posted a [question of questionable quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959837/how-do-i-stop-my-twitter-from-automatically-updating-my-facebook-status) <sup>10k+</sup> on Stack Overflow, and within a few seconds, a [spammy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18959861/938089) <sup>Now deleted by three users</sup> was posted. I've flagged the answer for spam, and voted to close the question.

Within two minutes, the question was closed and deleted. If I recall correctly, the answer was also deleted automatically. However, after a page refresh, the answer was undeleted again.

[image: deleted question, undeleted answer]

I went to my flag history and saw that the SPAM flag was disputed. The [user profile of the spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2807279/zyan-mc) shows "1 Answer", but there are no answers listed:

> [image: 1 answers]

Though the activity tab does show the answer:

> [image: activity]

What's happening?

**EDIT**: Plot twist! A diamond moderator did undelete the post a minute after posting (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18959861/revisions). Probably not deliberately, is anything broken?

> [image: undeleted by diamond moderator]

Comment: Seems to be gone again now

Comment: Not for me, the answer is still undeleted, and the user profile is still in an inconsistent state. @RichardTingle

Comment: interesting, I wonder if its something about being >10k, that it is deleted really (for us lowly <10kers) but its not showing the deleted text for you

Comment: @RichardTingle Only 10k+ can see other deleted posts.

Comment: I see "1 Answer" on the users profile, and the answer is not deleted in the question. It's been 25 minutes since the question's been deleted, so it seems a bit late for it to be a caching issue. But people are voting to delete the answer, which will ruin the validity of this report...

Comment: Wierd. For me, at this second both of the links in your question show "Page Not Found This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation. Please refer to the help center for possible explanations why a question might be removed."

Comment: @RichardTingle - You have to have over 10,000 reputation on SO to see deleted posts, which is what the OP is linking to.

Comment: My first reflex was to flag as NAA. But then I realised how I got there.

Comment: @nickb I must admit I'm wildly confused, I thought the point was that the question **should be** deleted but hasn't been? If it has been deleted then whats the problem? Is it only the strange flag behaviour

Comment: I cast the final delete vote. It now says when you try and undelete it that "Answers to deleted questions cannot be undeleted"

Comment: This "However, after a page refresh, the answer was undeleted again." is the bit thats confusing me

Comment: @RichardTingle I've edited my question, I've found something at the revision history (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176013/169101).

Comment: @RichardTingle - So the problem is that the question *was* deleted, but an answer within it appeared not to be. On the person who answered the question's profile, we could still see "1 Answer", as if the user posted an answer, but the view that should list all of the users answers was blank. Additionally, on the deleted question's page, posts that are deleted get a purple-ish background and say that they are deleted. This normally happens with all deleted questions, that all of the associated answers also get deleted. This does not seem to be the case, as the answer in question was not purple.

Comment: Whoah, that is odd; I don't recall undeleting that post, and certainly would not have done so consciously!