# Open modal links in reviews (close votes, suggested edits, etc.) in a new tab

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, user-interface, hyperlinks

I don't know UI principles, so just correct me if my argument is unfounded.

I would like links in modals (e.g. reviews) to open in a new tab. For example,

[image: The "Why should this be question closed?" window.]

To me, the modal represents a *transient* view—a temporary popup for specifying details. I think links *from* these views, therefore, should *also* appear in transient views—*i.e.* as an opportunity to peer at the FAQ or other information related to the judgment. But the judgment itself shouldn't fall out of focus. For example, in the "off topic" pane, links to the migrateable sites *do* open in new tabs, which I like:

[image: The "Closing > This question..." window.]

In the "duplicate" pane, it's mixed:

[image: The "Closing > Duplicate" window.]

Is it that it's too messy to try to convert links for "pulled" content? But it doesn't appear to be an `iframe`, so I don't see why that would be the case. (The question's title *does* open in a new tab, though.)

The suggested edits modal also has a link that doesn't open in a new tab:

[image: The "Why are you rejecting this edit?" window.]

Comment: Please yes! I am always accidentally clicking one of those links and having to go back.. sometimes it makes me miss a review. Oh the horror!

Comment: @Seth - Yes, that reminds me of another point. Those radio buttons are conveniently activated by clicking on the label (the text), which is great, but the color of visited links (as you can see in my screenshots) make the links hard to see sometimes, causing me to click the text _on_ the link, when I meant only to activate the radio button.

Comment: @Seth Also, I'd like to add to it that upon clicking on these links shouldn't close the currently opened model-box. :P

Comment: That would be very good ⊙■□●○●□■⊙ +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was expecting the moderator to add an answer as well when I flagged this question for being moved to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but since he did not, and I'd like to accept an answer:

I noticed yesterday that all of the links accessible via the review queue's lightbox pages for suggested edits, as well as for the various closing reasons, now open in new tabs. (Except for links *within* the potential-duplicate previews, but that's understandable, IMO.) As before, the other review queues are empty, so I didn't check *everything*, but the ones mentioned in the question all check out.

Thanks!

Comment: Yep, the change was done back in [July 29](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190888/152859) as part of declining a related feature request. :)