# The links in the closing and flagging dialogs should have consistent target attribute

Tags: bug, user-interface, hyperlinks, flag-dialog

According to the completed feature request [Have links in the Closing > Off-Topic dialog open in new tabs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186527/have-links-in-the-closing-off-topic-dialog-open-in-new-tabs), the links in the Closing > Off-topic dialog open in a new tab.  So do the links on the first page of the closing dialog (for users with 3K).

But the links in the *flagging* dialog open in the same window:

> [image: dialog]

Actually, not always: if one selects "should be closed" and then clicks "Flagging" to go back, the dialog is the same but the links, mysteriously, now have `target="_blank"`.

Whichever way it is, the links should behave consistently.

Comment: See, that's what happens when a site opens that can of worms -- "instead of following a consistent standard that everybody knows about, we'll change our behavior in *this* case... oh wait, then we also need to change it in *this other* case... and what about...?"  SE should never have gone down this path in the first place. :-(