# Enlarge the clickable area of closing reasons

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, user-interface

Only the text and the radio button of closing reasons are clickable. However, a full-width clickable area would be easier to hit and less frustrating. IIRC, this was also possible in the past.

Current situation:
[image: Current situation]

Proposed situation:
[image: Proposed situation]

Comment: +1: I don't really care, but you can have my support anyway because it makes sense.

Comment: I agree this would be an improvement, but feel compelled to mock your ability to use a mouse. It's ok people, I can say that, I have the misfortune of knowing him

Comment: @thecoshman: +1 for "misfortune"

Comment: Thank you, @thecoshman. You've never been so kind.

Comment: @thecoshman I suck at precise clicking (I’m horrible at first-person shooters). This is definitely an issue for me.

Comment: Why not include the area around the radio as well? That is probably the most common area to click, so that would help too

Comment: sometimes I'm so frustrated because I click right near the radio button instead of right ON the radio button. >.<

Comment: At the same time, the links in the close reasons should be made inactive. It's rather annoying to hit them when you want to select a reason.

Comment: Please do this on all dialogs, including the ones we see in the moderator queue. It would make it a lot easier to use a touch-screen device.

Comment: Related: [Can the links be disabled in the vote-to-close dialog?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136270/can-the-links-be-disabled-in-the-vote-to-close-dialog)

Comment: Like @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I've never had a problem with this, but I'll gladly upvote it for you and your fellow mouseically challenged SE users.

Comment: Seven hours and nobody has complained about the lack of free-hand circles. What's wrong today?

Comment: @rightfold: I just assumed you'd drawn them in white because well, like thecoshman I know you.

Comment: I've nearly _always_ accidentally click on [the area between the title and the description](http://i.imgur.com/jU9Rblz.png) (which is not clickable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been implemented and it's currently live. Not sure when it was enacted, though (it's not in [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) as far as I can tell), so maybe a team member can include it in its proper spot there?

Comment: I don't think it's major enough to be worth including there, it's just a minor design change. (Useful, but still minor.)